# SQL2 - Get child node properties

Tags: aem, jcr, jcr-sql2

This seems like a rather simple query but I've been banging my head for hours on this. I've got a node structure similar to below:

```
food-group
    jcr:content
        nuts -> type=almonds
        meat -> beef=true
        fruit -> type=apples,oranges,bananas
```

There are three types of properties I need to gather from my child nodes: one that is a string, boolean and string array. I would think that the following sql2 query would work and get the properties of them but for whatever reason I'm getting an error:

QUERY

```
SELECT 
    parent.* 
FROM 
    [cq:PageContent] AS parent 
INNER JOIN 
    [nt:base] as child ON ISCHILDNODE(parent) 
WHERE 
    ISDESCENDANTNODE(parent, [/content/grocerystore/food/])"
```

ERROR:

```
Need to specify the selector name because the query contains more than one selector.
```

Any help is appreciated as I've been at this for the past few days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two places the `ISCHILDNODE` function can be used in a JCR-SQL2 query: in the `WHERE` clause and in the join criteria. Unfortunately, they take different parameters.

Your query is attempting to use the `ISCHILDNODE` in the *join criteria*, which requires two parameters: the selector name for the child nodes, and the selector name for the parent nodes.

Here's the query I think you want:

```
SELECT parent.* 
FROM [cq:PageContent] AS parent 
INNER JOIN [nt:base] as child ON ISCHILDNODE(child,parent) 
WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(parent, [/content/grocerystore/food/])
```

The only change is the parameters to the `ISCHILDNODE` function.

Unfortunately, the error message doesn't really make this clear. To understand why, it helps to know about the other form of `ISCHILDNODE` - the one used in the `WHERE` clause. That form also takes *two* parameters: the name of the selector that will represent the child nodes, and the literal path of the parent (under which the resulting nodes are children). Here's a contrived query that uses this form:

```
SELECT node.*
FROM [nt:base] AS node
WHERE ISCHILDNODE(node,[/content/grocerystore])
```

The query result would contain all nodes that are children of the `/content/grocerystore` node.

Now, if the query defines just one selector (e.g., a non-join), then there is only one selector name that can be passed to the `ISCHILDNODE` function. Strictly speaking, the selector is implicitly known, so JCR-SQL2 allows you to pass in just the path. Here's a query that is semantically identical to the previous contrived example:

```
SELECT node.*
FROM [nt:base] AS node
WHERE ISCHILDNODE([/content/grocerystore])
```

This is the only form of the `ISCHILDNODE` that takes a single parameter, and I think this is the form that I think CQ5 is expecting: the error says that the query defines more than one selector, so the selector must be supplied as the first parameter.

Of course, this is very misleading because you're actually using the form of the function that appears in the join criteria. A better error message would say that function requires the child selector name and the parent selector name.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @RandallHauch, but for whatever reason I'm still getting the same error. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have the exact same query you wrote but getting the same error: – **WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(parent, [/content/grocerystore/food/]) AND (type =(*)'almonds'); expected: Need to specify the selector name for "type" because the query contains more than one selector.** Any ideas? I condensed the error message for everything after the ISDESCENDANTNODE. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: The error message is exactly right this time. Your query has more than one selector (aka, table), so you have to specify which selector all properties (aka, columns) come from. In other words, the `type=...` condition in the WHERE clause needs to include the selector name (e.g., table). Since that property appears on the child node, try `WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(parent, [/content/grocerystore/food/]) AND (child:type ='almonds')`. Also, I'm not sure what the `(*)` is in the criteria, so I left it off.

Comment: Thanks for the help @RandallHauch except when I try what you sent over I get a **Need to specify the selector name for "child"**

Answer (score 1):

This exception will be thrown if you invoke `getNodes()` method on a `QueryResult` that have more than one selector (in your case it's `parent` and `child`). This method will also be used if you call `findResources()` on the `ResourceResolver`.

Use the `QueryResult#getRows()` method instead:

```
Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
QueryManager queryManager = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();
Query query = queryManager.createQuery("...", Query.JCR_SQL2);
QueryResult result = query.execute();
// consider using result.getColumnNames() here
RowIterator rows = result.getRows();
while (rows.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rows.nextRow();
    // use row.getValue() or row.getValues()
}
```

A few remarks:

1. You need to fix the SQL query adding `child` as the first parameter to the `ISCHILDNODE(parent)`.
2. Pass properties list explicite in the `SELECT` clause rather than using `parent.*`, so you don't have to invoke `result.getColumnNames()`.
3. The query is quite complex and the way to invoke it is even more complex. Why don't you use Sling methods to iterate over the `food` space in your repository? It seems to be a perfect use-case for iterating over the tree.

   - You may be also interested in the [SlingQuery](https://github.com/Cognifide/Sling-Query) project.

Comment: You are correct that calling `getNodes()` on the results of a query that define multiple selectors will result in an exception. But that's not the problem that the question outlined. The query in the question is actually invalid, and the error is attempting (and failing) to explain what the problem actually is. (See my answer for details.)